# Smart-table search with submitting

Tags: angularjs, api, smart-table

I used smart-table to get a set of data from my API. Now I used the st-search property to search several parameters.

But I don't want the table to update the query every time I am using an input. I want to use a submit button to minimize the requests to the API.

I thought I could use the `st-input-event=` property from the table. But the documentation is very unclear and I'm not sure how to use this. Could someone provide me with an example? I'm still working out Angular.

```
<form class="no-gutters">
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label for="search-content" class="sr-only">Zoekopdracht</label>
    <input type="search" class="form-control search-content" id="search-content" placeholder="Zoekopdracht" st-search="orderID" ng-model="searchInput">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="search-type" class="sr-only">Paymethods</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedPayMethod" ng-options="(method.code | paymethod) for method in payMethods track by method.code" id="search-type" class="form-control search-type" st-search="paymentMethod">
        <option value="">Select payment method</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="search-period" class="sr-only">Periode zoekopdracht</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedDate" ng-options="date.name for date in dateSelection track by (date.date | date : 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sss')" id="search-period" class="form-control search-period" st-search="dateFrom">
        <option value="">Select period</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-m">Zoeken</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: that's not what a smart-table markup looks like

Answer (score 1):

If `st-search` does not suit your need, then you can always revert to the plain Angular way, remove the directive, add an `ng-model` to the input and use a button to submit what's inside the model.

Then use a filter inside the `ng-repeat` of the table and filter by the response of the submit

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nySUFy?p=preview) to demonstrate what I have in mind.